# View.setPadding accepts only in px, is there anyway to setPadding in dp?

Tags: android, android-layout

Android function `View.setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)` only accepts values in px but I want to set padding in dp. Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 207, accepted):

Straight to code

```
int padding_in_dp = 6;  // 6 dps
final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int padding_in_px = (int) (padding_in_dp * scale + 0.5f);
```

Comment: Hi, I have a question. Is this formula used for only padding or anything else? e.g. margin or dimmension of a rectangle?

Comment: This is the formula for [Converting dp units to pixel units](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#dips-pels). You can use it anywhere

Comment: I assume the `getResources()` is a function that is inherited by an activity, but I'm trying to use these lines in a custom listview adapter. Is there any way I can do this if I can't call `getResources()`?

Comment: From your adapter just do getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

Comment: Is there an explanation somewhere for the "+ 0.5f"?

Comment: My guess is the +0.5f is there to guarantee rounding up instead of rounding down when integer conversion is done? Should behave like Math.ceil.

Answer (score 105):

If you define the dimension (in dp or whatever) in an XML file (which is better anyway, at least in most cases), you can get the pixel value of it using this code:

```
context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.your_dimension_name)
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a better way to convert value to dp programmatically:

```
int value = 200;
int dpValue = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            value,        
            context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Then apply `dpValue` to your method, for example: `setPadding(dpValue,dpValue,dpValue,dpValue);`

Answer (score 2):

Here's Kotlin version based on accepted answer:

```
fun dpToPx(dp: Int): Int {
    val scale = resources.displayMetrics.density
    return (dp * scale + 0.5f).toInt()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the pixels for a specific DPI value: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=6284958&postcount=31

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem. The only solution i've found (it will not really help you :) ) is to set it in the Xml file.

If you can get the density from the code, you can use the convertion: "The conversion of dip units to screen pixels is simple: pixels = dips * (density / 160)." (from http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html )

Edit: you can get the screen density: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#densityDpi