# How to set android:layout_width="match_parent" from code?

Tags: android

I've different layout. Some created by xml. Some others dynamically via code. When I am on xml I can set width or height with "wrap_content" value. How to get the same result dynamically? This is the snippet of my dynamic TextView. I need to remove "final int width = 440;" and get same value of "wrap_content". How?

```
final int width = 440;
final int height = textViewHeight;
final int top = getNewTop(height);

FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;
layoutParams = getLayoutParams(width, height, top);

TextView textView;
textView = new TextView(_registerNewMealActivity);
textView.setText(text);
textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

_frameLayout.addView(textView);
```

Comment: You see wrap_content in google?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try out as below:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;
layoutParams = getLayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, height, top);

  TextView textView;
textView = new TextView(_registerNewMealActivity);
textView.setText(text);
textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use :

`textView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, height));`

Comment: +1 for mentioning FrameLayout and not RelativeLayout

Comment: @ArunkumarSharma : can you pls tell how it is different, actually always really confused when using LayoutParams, that which one should i import, or if you can please suggest any link or post.

Comment: @VishwasSharma `LayoutParams are used by views to tell their parents how they want to be laid out.` [Check This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html)

Comment: So we use the FrameLayout variation of LayoutParams because the TextView is being added to a FrameLayout? And if it were being added to a LinearLayout should we use LinearLayout.LayourParams, for example?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` for `width`

Answer (score 2):

In general, you should use

```java
textView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, height));
```

where `width` and `height` are each one of the following:

- A number, to make the view exactly that many pixels wide or tall (to specify a number in dp instead of pixels, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4275797/4284627))
- `FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT`
- `FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT`

Also, if you're using `LinearLayout`, you should use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` instead, and the same for `RelativeLayout`.

For example, if you want `textView` to have the same behavior as if it was declared as `<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>`, you would do

```java
textView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams flparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,(int)height);
            youlayoutname.setLayoutParams(flparams);
```

Answer (score -3):

try this>>>

```
layoutParams.getLayoutParams().width = 20;
```