# MP android chart Linechart layout params

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I want to plot 12 line graphs. So I put a linear layout inside a scrollview. I will be populating the linear layout with 12 charts. I want each chart to have height equal to width of the screen(since I am viewing graphs in landscape mode). My code goes like this :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private var screenHeight = 0
private var screenWidth = 0

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
    windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
    screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels
    screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels
    Log.i("width", screenWidth.toString())
    Log.i("height", screenHeight.toString())

    val chartHeight = screenHeight / 12
    for (i in 0..11){
        val lineChart = LineChart(this)
        lineChart.layoutParams.height = chartHeight  //line 33 giving error
        linearLayout.addView(lineChart)
    }
}
}
```

I am having the following problems :

1. I want to put width of linechart as `LayoutParams.match_parent` but when IDE asks me to import class `LayoutParams`, the options I get are `RelativeLayout`, `FrameLayout`, `ViewGroup` and many others but any one among them is not related to `LineChart`.
2. I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512854/how-to-set-androidlayout-width-match-parent-from-code) but its not working for LineChart. I don't know why. I am getting this error :

> AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                  Process: atharva.example.com.graphlist, PID: 29323
>                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{atharva.example.com.graphlist/atharva.example.com.graphlist.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: **Attempt to write to field 'int
>   android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.width' on a null object
>   reference**
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5476)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:229)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1827)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7329)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
>
> **Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.width' on a null object
>   reference**
>                                                                                      **at atharva.example.com.graphlist.MainActivity$override.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:33)**
>                                                                                      at
>   atharva.example.com.graphlist.MainActivity$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.kt)
>                                                                                      **at atharva.example.com.graphlist.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:0)**
>                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)

3. What does error at line 0 (referring to the above error log) mean?

Please help me in setting layout params through kotlin code for custom view like MP Android LineChart

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set the width value of your chart. Try to create new `LayoutParams` object. That worked for me.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams([your_width], [your_height]);
lineChart.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Hope it helps.